# CodeIgniter curtir publicação e mostrar como curtida

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um script de publicação, curtir e descurtir, porém quando coloco a opção para ser curtida começa meu erro.

```
SE ( ID_PERFIL = ID_PERFIL e ID_PUBLICACAO= ID_PUBLICACAO ) { CURTIU } SE NAO { CURTIR }
```

Porém quando eu faço essa requisição no banco *row_array()*.

O resultado sempre traz o primeiro da lista e somente o primeiro item curtido aparece como curtido, os demais não aparecem pois ele entra na negação.

se o primeiro é *23*, ele pega *23 = 23*, o segundo sendo *17*, ele ainda pega *23 = 17* e não aparece com curtido.

> MODEL

```
public function publicacao_curtida(){
$this->db->select('*, publicacao.id as id_publicacao');
$this->db->from('publicacao');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id = publicacao.id_profile');
$this->db->join('publicacao_like', 'publicacao.id = publicacao_like.id_publicacao');
$this->db->order_by("publicacao.id DESC");
//$this->db->order_by("rand()");
//$this->db->limit(5);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row_array(); }
```

> HTML

```
        <?php if($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $publicacao_curtida["id_profile"] && $publicacao_curtida["id_publicacao"] == $public->id_publicacao){ ?>
            <a href="#" onclick="descurtir_postagem(<?php echo $public->id_publicacao ?>)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="color:#0093D6;"></i> Curtiu</a>
        <?php }else{ ?> 
            <a href="#" onclick="curtir_postagem(<?php echo $public->id_publicacao ?>)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i> Curtir</a>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pegar todos os resultados de uma consulta use `result_array()` ou apenas `result()` (que devolve um array de objetos). `row_array()` retornar apenas um resultado/linha do banco de dados.

Comment: Ainda não foi bem o que estou precisando...

Quando curtem eu salvo no banco que curtiram.
Logo quero comparar se EU ja curti aquela postagem ou outras.

Sendo que quando eu comparo, ele apenas aparece como curtido o primeiro post.

ou quando crio um foreach ele mostra quantos curtir tem salvo na tabela